# Wrap a single html tag around each block that's generated from a single view

Tags: theming

I'm sure this isn't difficult, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have about 10 block displays generated from one view that needs a single html wrap (Setting the css property in the view itself is not what I'm looking for).  Devel themer module is suggesting block--views.tpl.php, however that obviously affects all blocks generated by views.  I assume a preprocess function would be best. The function below works, but I need to target a specific view.

Thanks in advance.

```
  function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['block']->module == 'views') {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('semester-container');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, but I was able to figure it out using the preprocess_block function.

```
  function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    kpr($variables); //Find a common element then add to the conditional below
    if ($variables['block']->module == 'views' && $variables['block']->context == 'curriculum_semester_breakouts') {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('semester-container');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by madhurjya is correct, but I would point out that it is possible to create a template that is applied to all block displays of a certain view. E.g. for a view Blog with Unformatted type of output you can use `views-view-unformatted--blog--block.tpl.php` to alter all blocks only from that view.

Explore the Theme:Information in the Advanced settings of a view to see all your options.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to encapsulate each block with same tag, this includes the block title.  The template file you suggested only effects the inner content of the block, which I'm currently using as well. Maybe I'm not utilizing the template file properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use function [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to customize the html, or u can use the view theme templates which u will get for each view block display by clicking on advance tab of view configuration page and for documentation on views template you can read [this link](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/).hope this will help u.

Following is one of my view, array of `$view`, Here you can see under the `display`, i have total five display between that i have two blocks block_1 & block_2 each block has its id as unique so you can modify ur code based on this `$view->display['block_1']->id` so on....
Hope this will. help you.

[image]

Comment: How would I break the result to target each block?

Comment: http://codeshare.io/aYb9z

Comment: see my edit on my answer.

Comment: Thank you Madhurjya.  Since I have over 10 blocks displaying at once, can't I target all blocks in a particular view rather than calling each by their machine name?